# Subset a lascatalog point cloud within a function while calculating grid_metrics

Tags: r, filter, point-cloud, lidr, grid-metrics

I am trying to create subsets of a point cloud based on the `ScanAngleRank` and compute some metrics for each subset. Then return a stack of `values(rasters)` for the metric. I modified the rumple index example as shown below:

```
met_calc = function(cluster, res)
{
  las = readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)

  outlist <- list()
  for(i in y){
    ls <- lasfilter(las, abs(ScanAngleRank) >= min(i) & abs(ScanAngleRank) < max(i))
    if (is.empty(ls)) return(NULL)
    out <- grid_metrics(ls,~mean(Z),res)
    outlist <- c(outlist,out)
  }
  #bbox   <- raster::extent(cluster)
  #outlist <- raster::crop(outlist, bbox)
  return(outlist) 
}

opt_chunk_buffer(ldr) <- 1
opt_chunk_size(ldr) <- 300
opt_select(ldr) <- "*"
opt <- list(raster_alignment = 20, automerge = TRUE)
output <- catalog_apply(ldr, met_calc, res = 20, .options = opt)

y <- list(0:10, 10:20, 20:30, 30:40, 40:50)
```

In the first iteration, for example, I tried to subset `las` for minimum and maximum scan angle of 0 and 10 degerees respectively, and so on. In this case, that means 5 rasters.

`bbox` and `outlist` are comments because they were generating errors.

I get the following warning:

```
The list returned by 'catalog_apply' contains unsupported objects. Merging is impossible. A list has been returned.
```

`Output` is a complicated list of `RasterLayer`s for small areas.

I tried using `grid_metrics()` to return a `list` of metrics as shown in the example in the documentation. Have not been able to figure that.

I understand how to work with a single las file. My confusion is with the usage of `LAScatalog` and related options for this purpose, efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outlist` is a `list`. The output of `catalog_apply()` is thus a `list` with one element per chunk and each element is a `list`. The engine is not able to merge such complex output with nested lists. So `automerge` option fails and the output is the regular, unmerged, list + a warning to tell you that `automerge` did nothing.

You are trying compute mean elevation for different subsets with more or less points with large angles. Instead of returning a `list` of `RasterLayer` you could return a `RasterStack` or a `RasterBrick`.

```r
met_calc = function(cluster, res)
{
  las = readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)

  # Creation of a layout so each raster will be the same
  # no matter the content of the point cloud
  layout <- grid_metrics(las, ~length(Z), res)
  layout[] <- NA # see issue #318

  y <- list(0:50, 5:20, 10:20, 5:8, 2:6)

  # Initialize a first layer
  i <- y[[1]]
  ls <- lasfilter(las, abs(ScanAngleRank) >= min(i) & abs(ScanAngleRank) < max(i))
  out <- grid_metrics(ls,~mean(Z), layout)

  # Loop on other layers
  for(i in y[-1])
  {
    ls <- lasfilter(las, abs(ScanAngleRank) >= min(i) & abs(ScanAngleRank) < max(i))

    if (!is.empty(ls))
      r <- grid_metrics(ls, ~mean(Z), layout)
    else # if empty we have to return something anyway
      r <- layout

    out <- raster::addLayer(out, r)
  }

  # crop the buffer
  bbox   <- raster::extent(cluster)
  out <- raster::crop(out, bbox)
  names(out) <- c("0:50", "5:20", "10:20", "5:8", "2:6")
  return(out) 
}

library(lidR)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
ldr = readLAScatalog(LASfile)

opt_chunk_buffer(ldr) <- 1
opt_chunk_size(ldr)   <- 200
opt_chunk_alignment(ldr) <- c(60,60)
opt_select(ldr)       <- "*"
opt <- list(raster_alignment = 10, automerge = TRUE)
output  <- catalog_apply(ldr, met_calc, res = 10, .options = opt)

plot(output)
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou! Processing using LAScatalog is something I haven't been able to grasp very well yet! I was ready to subset and execute manually! Would you say this (the answer) is the most efficient way of creating such subsets? It would be nice to be able to subset the data in a custom function for grid_metrics(), for example.

Comment: I acknowledge that it is not straightforward. We are currently writing an extensive vignette that document in depth the engine. I hope it will help. For feature request ask on github or by email.

Comment: Update: It worked well for a small area which I was testing upon to save time. On applying it to a larger area (more las tiles), the function returns the same complicated list structure. Everything is the same except for the data. Was wondering if it is a random error? Didnt think a new question would be very helpful as everything is the same.

Comment: Followup: So what was happening with the larger area is that there was an error in reading some chunk and the program stopped working. I used the 'opt_stop_early(ldr) <- FALSE' option. Didn't understand why there was an error in the first place. Hope this information is helpful. I guess this is a difference I didn't mention in the previous comment.

Comment: You can report bug on [github](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR) or by email if you think you found a bug